# Synchronizing events of my system into most widely used calendars

Tags: calendar, synchronization, icalendar

I have implemented a (sports field) booking system. I would like to add one feature: when a customer makes a booking I would like to offer him the possibility to get/sync his newly created entry in his own calendar.

One solution what I already found is to create an iCalendar feed for the customer with his bookings. So he can take this feed (basically an URL pointing to a user-specific .ics file) and integrate it into his calendar applications (as most will support the addition of external calendars).
One bottleneck with this solution is that a good amount of customers use Gmail and its calendar. And it may take some time until Gmail refreshes external calendars. So it may take up to few hours until the newly created entry appears in the customers calendar.
Of course there's no such problem when customer is using calendar apps which offer more frequent or on-demand synchronization.

So my question here: what other solutions can you recommend? An export in a file for the newly created event? Or any other technology to sync our bookings with the most widely used calendars? What would be the most usable solution for customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to auto update / synchronise the booking by having the user subscribe,  then the ics feed is the standard cross application way to do it.

If it is just one booking and is never going to be updated, then you could encourage them to import the ics file to their calendar which usually then appears within seconds.

You can also email them the ics file.  It is then not subscribeable as it is NOT a url.  How it is handled depends on their email and system setup, but most would offer import into their calendar. (Mine opens in notepad++) ;)